# Detectar palabras de un String

Tags: java

Hola soy nuevo en Java,

Estoy intentando crear un *setter* llamado `setSurname` que haga lo siguiente:

Si el apellido que se quiere asignar a un atleta es mayor a 50 carácteres entonces, setSurname no tiene que asignar este apellido al atleta i tiene que imprimir por pantalla el mensaje: "ERROR".

En caso contrario, se tiene que asignar el apellido al atributo surname, teniendo en cuenta que las letras del apellido tienen que guardarse en mayúsculas y que si el apellido está formado por dos nombres separados por un espacio, estos tienen que ser substituïdos por el carácter '_'. Por ejemplo: `setSurname ("Gil Garcia")` tiene que ser `surname = "GIL_GARCIA"`.

Por el momento he hecho lo siguiente:

```
private void setSurname (String surname) {
if(surname.length > 50) {
System.out.println("ERROR")
}else{
// Aquí vendría la condición de reemplazar el espacio por "_" y en mayúsculas.
this.surname = surname.toUpperCase()
}
}
```

El caso es que no sé como detectar que haya diferentes palabras en el String, sólo se me ocurre la posibilidad de pasarlo todo a mayúsculas pero no se hacer el tratamiento de:

Si el apellido está formado por dos nombres separados por un espacio, estos tienen que ser substituïdos por el carácter '_'

La solución:

```
 public void setSurname (String surname){
        if (surname.length() > 50) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's surname cannot be longer than 50 characters");
        }else{
            surname= surname.replaceAll(" ", "_");
            this.surname = surname.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Añadí la solución.

Comment: de hecho lo ideal es agregar las soluciones en la parte de respuestas. Saludos.